# stylus-toolbox can't write to /dev/lp0

Tags: 11.10, printing

On Ubuntu 11.10 I try to monitor ink levels with stylus-toolbox.  I have a Epson SX100. Firstly it defaults to /dev/usb/lp0 which doesn't exist.  I changed it to /dev/lp0 which does exist. Then it had read/write issues so I did `sudo chown donald /dev/lp0` and put myself in the lp group.

Then stylus-toolbox got further but reported "Cannot write to /dev/lp0: Resource temporarily unavailable."  Stylus-toolbox worked OK on maverick without any problems but doesn't work on Oneiric.  This means that I have to go the Windows XP to find which ink cartridge is empty.  This is the only thing I need in XP otherwise I would ditch it!

Answer (score 1):

I have the same in xubuntu 11.10.
found in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups/+bug/842823

comment  usblp from blacklist:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-cups-usblp.conf
```

like:

# cups talks to the raw USB devices, so we need to blacklist usblp to avoid

# grabbing them

#blacklist usblp